# Airflow not calling sla_miss_callback function

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to add SLA slack alerts for our airflow. Our `slack_failure_notification` works fine, but I've been unable to get airflow to call `sla_miss_callback`.

I've seen in multiple threads people saying to put the `sla_miss_callback` in the dag definition and NOT in the `default_args`. If I do this, the dag runs fine, and my `test_task` gets inserted into the sla miss table, but it says notification sent = False and never seems to trigger the `sla_miss_callback` function. Looking at the task instance details, it has sla = 0:01:00 and has an on_failure_callback attribute but no sla_miss_callback attribute (not sure if it is supposed to have that or not).

```
def slack_failure_notification(context):
    failed_alert = SlackWebhookOperator(
        task_id='slack_failure_notification',
        http_conn_id='datascience_alerts_slack',
        message="failed task")
    return failed_alert.execute(context=context)

def slack_sla_notification(dag, task_list, blocking_task_list, slas, blocking_tis):
    alert = SlackWebhookOperator(
        task_id='slack_sla_notification',
        http_conn_id='datascience_alerts_slack',
        message="testing SLA function")
    return alert.execute()

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1),
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'on_failure_callback': slack_failure_notification
}

dag = DAG('template_dag', default_args=default_args, catchup=False, schedule_interval="10 13 * * *", sla_miss_callback=slack_sla_notification)

test_task = SnowflakeOperator(
    task_id='test_task',
    dag=dag,
    snowflake_conn_id='snowflake-static-datascience_airflow',
    sql=somelongrunningcodehere,
    sla=datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
)
```

If I instead put `sla_miss_callback` in `default_args`, the task still gets put into the sla miss table, and it says notification sent = True, but the `sla_miss_callback` function still never triggers. I also see nothing in our log files.

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1),
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'on_failure_callback': slack_failure_notification,
    'sla_miss_callback': slack_sla_notification
}
```

I have also tried defining the function using `def slack_sla_notification(*args, **kwargs):` with no change in behavior.

I know the airflow developers say the SLA stuff is a bit of a mess and will be reworked at some point, but I'd love to get this to work in the meantime if anyone has any ideas of things to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to include context in your execute method.
If you just want to see your message, I would suggest something like this:

```py
def slack_sla_notification(dag, task_list, blocking_task_list, slas, blocking_tis):
    message = "testing SLA function"
    alert = SlackWebhookOperator(
        task_id='slack_sla_notification',
        http_conn_id='datascience_alerts_slack',
        message=message)
    return alert.execute(message)
```